# how to use gmaps.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gmaps.js

I have been playing around with gmaps.js lately. However, I can't get it work.

Here's the code.

In the header I imported these three files:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true

gmaps.js

```
<div id="mouse_event_map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * Mouse Events on Maps
 */
$(document).ready(function(){
 var map = new GMaps({
    el: '#mouse_event_map',
    lat: 51.5073346,
    lng: -0.1276831,
    zoom: 12,
    zoomControl : true,
    zoomControlOpt: {
        style : 'SMALL',
        position: 'TOP_LEFT'
    },
    panControl : false,
    click: function(e){
      alert('Click event');
    },
    dragend: function(e){
      alert('Drag Event');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think the official name is Google Maps API. And you'll have to put some effort into the question and explain how exactly it does not work.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using gmaps.js for Google Maps API. But I can't seem to get it work. Here's the link http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gmaps.js documentation](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/map_events.html) shows

```
map = new GMaps({
  div: '#map',
  zoom: 16,
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333,
  click: function(e) {
    alert('click');
  },
  dragend: function(e) {
    alert('dragend');
  }
});
```

Note that this uses `div` and not `el`.

Comment: good catch...so I changed the code to   <div id="map"></div> and div: '#map'  ...but it still does not work..

Comment: You still haven't explained what "not working" means.  Do you get javascript errors?  A grey map?  No map?

Comment: @ExtendLimit Perhaps you need to go back and read the gmaps.js documentation. Where is the size of your map specified? **Please give more details about what you see** -- or, if you can't describe it, then a link to your map so we can see what's going on.

Comment: The example in the documentation includes an external css file, without which it doesn't work... (and some external javascript that if not included causes it to fail at `prettyPrint();`, before the map is rendered)

Comment: ahh, i forgot the css file...added a few css lines, now it is working. Thanks so much.

Comment: Its actually missing the css for the map. If you add this it should be ok `#map,
#panorama {
  height:300px;
  background:#6699cc;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I was just struggling with the same issue - map wasn't showing up and I was following the tutorials to the 'T' ....

I got my map working by removing the '#' (ID) symbol from the 'el:' declaration.  This may help someone looking for answers. Still use the id - the map should show up.

### ex.

el: '#map',

### becomes:

el: 'map',